# Django - how to handle Http requests correctly in views.py

Tags: django

I have a beginner question here. 
Let's suppose that I have url which returns JSON array of objects from my database. Something like that:

```
def my_model_as_json(request):
    print "request to retrieve the rules list"
    if request.method == "GET":
        object_list = Policy.objects.all() #or any kind of queryset
        json_response = serializers.serialize('json', object_list, fields=('name', 'last_update'))
        return HttpResponse(json_response, content_type='application/json')
```

I know for sure that the request is GET, so is there any need to check any other conditions here?
Do I need to return something if the request method is not GET?

Comment: Why do you care what the method is? Why not just remove the condition and just return the response?

Comment: You should always return something, like a render method

Comment: @DanielRoseman is it a good practice, not to check which kind of request I'm dealing with? Or it just doesn't matter in my scenario?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, if the incomming request is not GET, then you will get an error since you only return an HttpResponse if the request is GET. If you don't rely on any input then you can simply omit the `if request.method == "GET"` and your code should work regardless.

Comment: When you say I'll get an error, you mean the client side will get an error, right? Since I am designing the client side as well, I know for sure that the request will be GET, why should I care if there is an error for POST request for example? I'm just trying to understand in what situation the request will be something else than GET, unless someone uses Postman or something to test my server functionality

Comment: @Keselme yes the client will get a `500 - Internal Server Error` most likely if there is a POST request. Since you are developing the client side yourselt it does not really matter and it will likely work flawlessly. It is just that it's not necessary to include the `if request.method == "GET"`, and if you don't your code will always return an httpresponse which is good practice even though it may never happen.